# SVG not showing in browser?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am using browsersync, and have an svg file I am trying to use as a css `background-image`

**SVG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="14px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 14 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title>Pause</title>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Player" transform="translate(-2710.000000, -394.000000)" fill="#ffffff">
            <g id="Pause" transform="translate(2710.000000, 394.000000)">
                <g id="Rectangle-131-+-Rectangle-131">
                    <rect id="Rectangle-131" x="0" y="0" width="5" height="20"></rect>
                    <rect id="Rectangle-131" x="9" y="0" width="5" height="20"></rect>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Chrome generally doesn't load something unless you need it.  How are you consuming the svg?

Comment: In passing, I note that having multiple elements with the same id is not valid. That's not the problem you're complaining about though.

Comment: Honestly I agree, I got this svg element from another place, soundcloud to be specific, I am trying to reuse the play button they have.

Comment: @FEA5T I am including it via css, originally I had linked directly to the source hosted by soundcloud, but I wanted to customize it so I downloaded it and included in my local file structure. So I am using it as `background-image: url(../images/svg/play.svg)`